# How to keep the sorting order while paging in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a spring application which utilize Spring MVC and Spring data. I am trying to enable paging and sorting in a view by using Pageable and Sort argument in my controller methods. Everything works fine for first page when I sort the results by title or date, but when I navigate to next page results are not ordered anymore my `mvcContext.xml` file is

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
                <property name="maxPageSize" value="3"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.its.stud"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and my jsp file is

```
 <c:forEach items="${page.content}" var="topic">
    <div class="topic-box">
        <div class="from-topicbov"  >
            <div class="form-topic-title">
                <h1<a href="<spring:url value="/logged?page=0&sort=title"/>">Title</a></h1>
                <p><a href="<spring:url value="/logged?page=0&sort=date"/>">Date</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <p >${topic.content}</p>
                    <div class="date">
                        <p><a href="<spring:url value="/logged/${topic.id}"/>">${topic.title}</a></p>
                        <p>${topic.date}</p>
                        <p>${topic.author}</p>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit" >comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

and in my controller class I use this method:

```
  @RequestMapping("/logged")
    public String welcome(Model model, Pageable page, Sort sort) {
        model.addAttribute("page",topicRepository.findAll(page));
        return "topics";
    }
```

Please advice.
EDIT: the repository

```
public interface TopicRepository extends JpaRepository<Topic,Long> {
}
```

Comment: You should perhaps also pass in the sort object into the repository.

Comment: I did read spring-data/data-commons/docs and repository and did not find anything pointing to my problem, can you please provide an example please

Comment: Your `topicRepository`, what kind of repository is this, can't you just pass your paging information to the query from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague of min I did find the solution. In order to maintain the sorting order, I have to pass the sort parameter to paging object, so it will be retained in other pages. To do so two steps must be taken. First, in the controller method, a sort parameter must be added to model attribute and it must pass the sort property

```
@RequestMapping("/logged")
public String welcome(Model model, Pageable page, Sort sort) {
    model.addAttribute("page",topicRepository.findAll(page));
    model.addAttribute("sort",(sort !=null)?sort.iterator().next().getProperty():"");
    return "welcome";
}
```

and finally in the jsp file, where the paging is performed, the sort parameter must be appended to the url

```
<c:forEach items="${page.content}" var="topic">
            <div class="form-topic-title">
                <h1><a href="<spring:url value="/logged?page=0&sort=title"/>">Title</a></h1>
                <p><a href="<spring:url value="/logged?page=0&sort=date"/>">Date</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <p >${topic.content}</p>
                    <div class="date">
                        <p><a href="<spring:url value="/logged/${topic.id}"/>">${topic.title}</a></p>
                        <p>${topic.date}</p>
                        <p>${topic.author}</p>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit" >comment</button>
            </div>
    </c:forEach>
    <a href="<spring:url value="/logged?page=${page.number - 1}&sort=${sort}"/>">Previous</a>
    <a href="<spring:url value="/logged?page=${page.number + 1}&sort=${sort}"/>">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even remove the Sort parameter because the Pageable interface has it already.
So the controller could be:

```
@RequestMapping("/logged")
public String welcome(Model model, Pageable page) {
    model.addAttribute("page",topicRepository.findAll(page));
    Sort sort = page.getSort();
    model.addAttribute("sort",(sort !=null)?sort.iterator().next().getProperty():"");
    return "welcome";
}
```